How does Teams know which physical room I am in?
At my workplace they recently upgraded some of the meeting rooms. They are now "Teams enabled". This includes a monitor, microphone, speaker and the possibility of joining Microsoft Teams meetings directly from the TV in the room.
If I bring my laptop to the meeting room and join the Teams meeting after the "room" has entered the meeting my laptop gives the message shown on the screenshot. This is useful since it avoids the echo of multiple microphones in the room (which everyone who have been in these types of meetings have experienced).
However, I cannot figure out how Teams know I am physically present in the meeting room. If I sit in another physical room it does not show this message.
I have considered a number of options such as testing for nearby wi-fi signals or a high pitched noise that the laptop picks up on.
Therefore, how does Teams detect that I am physically in the same room as the monitor that has already joined the meeting?


One possibility is there's a WIFI repeater in the room to which your device will connect as it will have the strongest signal. There could also be a dedicated WIFI network not used for data connection but just to detect the presences in the room (you can check this easily).  But it really also depends on how your workplace's LAN is configured.

IIRC Teams uses imperceptible sounds to identify room audio.

Microsoft Teams Rooms (MTRs) currently use Bluetooth beaconing to determine users' proximity to the system's compute unit.  This can cause issues where multiple room systems are installed close to each other or, conversely, when the compute unit is installed in a separate location outside of the room.  This feature is referenced in Microsoft's security and configuration documentation for MTRs.
To overcome these limitations, Microsoft is moving to proximity join via an ultrasonic signal from the touch panel in the room. It's currently in private preview and scheduled to start rolling out publicly in August 2024. You can view updates under Feature ID 380681.

Thank you for the answer! Sounds very plausible The coming update is described in the link you provide. However, do you have any similar link for the current functionality?

I edited my answer to include links to help documents that reference the current feature.

Was this a feature back in May, if it wasn’t, then it’s not an answer to the authors question. BT detection seems more likely

It was in private preview at the time, so there's a possibility the room was using the ultrasonic signal, but you're right that it was most likely Bluetooth.
